# AppstatsFilter and AppstatsServlet are unavailable in sdk 1.8.6 ?!

Tags: google-app-engine

Hi guys I am trying to profile my appengine application [I read this doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats) but I didn't find AppstatsFilter and AppstatsServlet ! Are they removed and replaced with something new or are they moved ot other packages ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue today and found the AppstatsFilter and AppstatsServlet inside the appengine-api-labs jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```